# Por que "a nível de" é considerado errado e como expressar a mesma ideia?

Tags: expressões

Há muito tempo aprendi com o [professor Pasquale](http://www.professorpasquale.com.br/site/home/index.php) que "a nível de" é uma expressão horrível. Nunca mais usei mas nunca aprendi o porquê disto. Qual é o problema?

Como podemos substituir esta expressão por algo melhor?

Exemplo:

> A nível de Brasil isto é muito dinheiro.

Comment: @DenisCaixeta porquê essa tag?

Comment: Acho que poderíamos criar essa tag, pois a expressão é um tipo de modismo da língua portuguesa. Neste site existem alguns exemplos: http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/modismos-linguisticos.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

O problema não é da expressão em si, é do uso exagerado que se fez dela naquela época (hoje ela parece menos usada). O que se criticava é que era possível transmitir a mesma ideia de maneira mais simples, e o "a nível de" acabava entrando na frase para dar um ar de erudição ao que estava sendo dito. Por exemplo, a frase que você citou poderia ser reescrita como

> No Brasil isto é muito dinheiro

O sentido não muda, mas tinha gente que achava mais "bonito" com "a nível de". E o que houve foi que isso se tornou uma mania, as pessoas saíram usando "a nível de" a torto e a direito. Virou um vício de linguagem.

É o mesmo caso do "gerundismo". Não está gramaticalmente errado dizer "vou estar enviando", mas geralmente é desnecessário. Acontece que tem gente, especialmente operadores de *telemarketing*, que adoram essas fórmulas, como se fosse isso que fosse sinônimo de educação e bom atendimento (quando na verdade todos nós preferiríamos ter o problema resolvido rapidamente). Eu diria até que é hipócrita. Em vez da moça dizer:

> Anota aí o protocolo e reza

Temos que encarar um

> A nível de protocolo, vou estar te dizendo um número, e vou pedir para o senhor estar anotando.

Comment: Creio que o *a nível de* não atingiu a nível de Portugal os níveis epidémicos que parece ter atingido a nível do Brasil. Temos é as "situações": já recebi uma carta do banco com «instruções relacionadas com situações de utilização do cartão» (acho que era mais elaborado, mas já não me lembro). Eu sabia que no Brasil há quem use *te* com *você*; mas *te* com *o senhor*?!

Answer (score 3):

A expressão "a nível" ou "a nível de" trata-se de um modismo muito empregado por pessoas que se julgam falar bonito. Para Almeida (2009), essa expressão, do ponto de vista formal, não existe no nosso idioma. O que temos de legítimo é a expressão "em nível".

> Exemplos:
>   (I) A reunião será realizada em nível federal.
>   (II) Este caso em nível jurídico é polêmico.

Mesmo a expressão "em nível" é dispensável. No exemplo (II) poderíamos dizer: este caso jurídico é polêmico.

No site a seguir também encontramos uma explicação:

> [A NÍVEL DE, EM NÍVEL DE ou AO NÍVEL DE?](http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/a-nivel-de-ou-em-nivel-de-saiba-qual-e-o-correto-e-quando-usar.html)
>   1. INACEITÁVEL. O grande erro quanto ao uso da expressão “a nível de” é sua utilização em situações em que não há “níveis”: “A nível de proposta, o assunto deve ser mais discutido”; “A nível de sentimento, isso é irreversível”; “A nível de relatório, só devemos descrever o essencial”; “A nível de gramática, isso está errado”...
>   2. ACEITÁVEL. Podemos usar a expressão “em nível” sempre que houver “níveis”: “Esse problema só pode ser resolvido em nível de diretoria” (=a empresa deve ter outros níveis hierárquicos); “Isso só acontece em nível municipal” (=poderia ser em nível estadual ou federal).
>   A expressão “ao nível do mar” é perfeitamente aceitável.

Vale lembrar que expressões como: "em termos de", "no que concerne a", "no que diz respeito a" são bem mais elegantes e apropriadas à língua culta.

**Referências bibliográficas**
ALMEIDA, Nilson Teixeira de. **Gramática da Língua Portuguesa**. 9 ed. São Paulo: Saraiva, 2009.
**'A nível de' ou 'em nível de'? Saiba qual é o correto e quando usar**. Disponível em: http://g1.globo.com/educacao/blog/dicas-de-portugues/post/a-nivel-de-ou-em-nivel-de-saiba-qual-e-o-correto-e-quando-usar.html. Acesso em: 24 jul. 2016.

Comment: Gosto de saber estas coisas. Mas esta posição do Almeida é radical à brava.